# Selecting 3 closest locations using latitude-longitude-postcode database

Tags: php, mysql, performance, latitude-longitude

I have a bit of a performance issue with my script, so I wonder if anyone knows a better way to approach this.

I have a database with locations and their postcodes(id, name, postcode). In another table I have latitude and longitude associated to postcodes(lat, long, postcode). The script asks user for a postcode and returns 3 closest locations.

The way I'm currently doing this, is first: I'm getting all the locations from db to a local array, then using a mysql query I'm getting distances between location and user's postcode for each location.

```
SELECT SQRT( POW( (
    uc1.lat - uc2.lat
    ), 2 ) + POW( (
    uc1.long - uc2.long
    ), 2 ) ) 
FROM postcodes uc1
LEFT JOIN postcodes uc2 ON uc1.postcode = "$postcode1"
WHERE uc2.code = "$psotcode2"
```

After that I sort the array and display first 3 elements.

This works fine if number of locations is small, but as they approach thousands performance becomes an issue.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I'm quite aware of curvature of the earth. I posted this query instead of more mathematically heavy one, so that it would be easier to understand what actually happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a "bounding box" to use in a WHERE clause in your SQL query as described [in this article on Movable Type](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html) (with PHP code examples), then include the Haversine formula in your query to calculate the actual distances, and order the result by distance ASC.

It's the bounding box that helps your performance, because it means you're only doing the expensive distance calculation on a small subset of your data

Comment: Sounds promising, I'll give this a try. Any suggestions on how to choose bounding box, so that to be sure that there is at least 3 locations inside it? Or should i just try with a small one, if less then 3 locations gets returned try the bigger one, and then bigger again?

Comment: I'd be inclined to go small and then increase the bounding box... store the returns from the first result, then for subsequent queries, you could use a double bounding box (a new, wider bounding box for inclusion, but with the previous bounding box to ignore this time)... that way, you're not recalculating the same results that were returned by the previous queries. It makes the code slightly more complex, and its better if you can get your full results in a single query, but should still be a lot faster than a full db search.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your distance calculation doesn't account for the curvature of the earth

You should look at using something like this

```
SELECT id, place_name,
((ACOS(SIN($lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(`lat` * PI() / 180) + COS($lat * PI() / 180) * COS(`lat` * PI() / 180) * COS(($lon – `lon`) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distance
FROM places
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do use a different query in my project, I just thought that math doesn't matter here. And will only abstract readability. Question was about performance, not about accuracy.